# Add negative hex numbers

Tags: assembly, x86, hex

I have a small problem:
Is there any value of `X` that satisfies this equation and can fit in a 32 bit register?

```
7A40B660+X=004023A0
```

I need it to do the call to the 004023A0 address (I control the ESI register):

```
.code:00401095 mov     eax, 7A40B660h
.code:0040109A add     eax, [esi]      ; Add
.code:0040109C call    eax
```

All are hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: It depends what representation is being used. For example, are these 32-bit numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's simply the problem:

7A40B660 + X = 004023A0

Let's put X by itself:

X = 004023A0 - 7A40B660

In 32-bit hex, `FFFFFFFF + 1 = 0`. And adding zero to a number doesn't change its value. So let's add zero to the right side:

X = FFFFFFFF + 1 + 004023A0 - 7A40B660

Rearranging:

X = (FFFFFFFF - 7A40B660) + 1 + 004023A0

Now it's easy to solve. The answer is 85FF6D40.

Comment: Hi. It didn't work. I am doing it to solve an ASM situation: http://pastebin.com/ZCbUwBf2 I control ESI and I want that the result of the add instruction is 004023A0. Thanks again!

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? What exactly did you do and what happened? Did you set `ESI` to an address that contained the value `85FF6D40`? What value wound up in `EAX`?

Comment: Yes I did it. Obviously EAX has value: `7A40B660` (mov     eax, 7A40B660h). So EAX=`7A40B660` and the pointer of ESI=`85FF6D40` but the value that is stored after the add in EAX is `BAAEB5E5`

Comment: @Alberto the value at the address must be that 85FF6D40, not (necessarily) the address itself.